# Как реализовать файлообменник?

Tags: php

Меня интересует техническая сторона, не надо типо "Зачем тебе это ? Замучиешься в судах и тп".

Подойдет ли Php как основной язык или какой желательно использовать? Какие основные функции? Вообщем хочу написать для себя аналог Megauplod.

Comment: Главное сразу позаботьтесь о горизонтальной расширяемости( в первую очередь стоит позаботится о вопросе хранения файлов ). Я бы не использовал PHP для загрузки и раздачи файлов, в остальном, думаю, проблем не будет... Только вот это и есть основной функционал любого файлообменника :)

Вообще я бы, на сервере использовал бы mongodb grid fs + node.js

Comment: Пост случаем никак не связан с этим [Megaupload готовится к возрождению, написано 90% кода][1] ? (:


  [1]: http://www.xakep.ru/post/59361/

Comment: Ну да связан

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для себя или аналог megaupload в прямом смысле?

Если для себя то PHP подойдёт.

Наладить загрузку файлов на сервер, помещать в специальную директорию. В mysql вести учёт каждого файла, статистику скачиваний и.т.д. Через javascript устанавливать задержки на скачивание. Учитывать пользователей по ip + браузер и дополнительно id в cookie.
Если пользователь прислал GET параметр file_id=видео_741. 
В базе смотрим id файла, вставляем к ссылке [my_site.ru/files/+адрес_пути_к_файлу.](http://my_site.ru/files/+адрес_пути_к_файлу.)
И делаем echo пользователю. Если обратиться по этому адресу должно начаться скачивание файла.

А вот уровня megaupload...

Хранить файлы у себя на серверах выйдет затратным учитывая, что скачивание будет с разных уголков мира, что приведет к задержкам в самых удаленных регионах.

Здесь нужен провайдер: Сеть доставки контента(Content Delivery Network).

База данных должна поддерживать масштабируемость и отказоустойчивость. 
Соответственно необходимо использовать что то вроде mysql cluster или oracle.

В качестве языка программирования для вывода html подойдёт PHP. 
А вот работа с СУБД, пользователями, платёжными системами,  контроль доступа должен обеспечивать надёжный и быстрый язык, например Си.

Comment: кластера реляционных бд от лукавого, это для тех, кто не в курсе.

Comment: Для себя и "аналог megaupload" - это кагбэ взаимоисключающие вещи :) Вы сначала с ТЗ определитесь, потом уже понятней станет. На вопрос "какие основные функции" ответ должен быть до.